# Firebug / inspect element on hide menu

Tags: firefox, firebug

I want to find an element in FireFox 13. The problem is that I can't right click on my element. This is due to the fact that my element is a hide menu, which open on left click, and close on right click.

There is any other option to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can click "Inspect Element" from Firebug instead the right-click menu.
2. In "Script" panel, you can also enable Break-On-Next (pause button) which will pause the debugger on the next JavaScript statement execution (i.e. on the event listener for click in your situation). You can also enable this with a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

[image: Firebug]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is opening the console tab and writing

```
 setTimeout(() => {debugger}, 5000)
```

This will trigger the debugger after 5 seconds. So as soon as u enter this command click on the menu and wait for the debugger to start and freeze your menu in place.

If 5 seconds is too little, increase the number 5000 as u see fit.